# Spinor reps in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\times{}B$ space-times

Tags: group-representations, dirac-equation, representation-theory, spinors, kaluza-klein

I am considering spinors in a space-time which is $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\times{}B$ being $B$ a compact manifold of $D$ dimensions.

I know that in ordinary 4 dimensional space-time spinors are representations of $O(1,3)$. Now, in my case, are spinors expected to be reps of $O(1,3+D)$?

Does the compactness of $B$ impose some restrictions to this? I have the feeling that we have to expect spinors to be reps of $O(1,3)\times{}O(D)$ since I don't feel that making a boost in the compact space is allowed but I am not sure.

Any clarification on the reps spinors are in in the mentioned space-time will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In 3+1 dimensions spinors do not transform under representations of $O(1,3)$, but under representations of the covering group $\operatorname{Spin}(1,3)$, which has the same Lie algebra. The structure group of a semi-Riemannian manifold is determined by the metric signature. Thus if the metric is such that $B$ is spacelike, spinors would transform under $\operatorname{Spin}(1,3+D)$.

(To define what I mean by the structure group: it is always possible to, locally, find a set of vector fields such that the metric is diagonal. This is since with respect to a local basis of vector fields the metric at every point in spacetime is a symmetric matrix. The structure group is the group of linear transformations that preserves this form of the metric. Indeed the Lorentz group is often defined as the group that preserves $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. By Sylvester's law of inertia the structure group is well-defined.)

A boost along the compact directions is allowed, because locally the space looks like $\mathbb{R}^{1,3+D}$ (for a spacelike $B$). It may be that the metric can be cast in a form $$ds^2 = ds_0^2 + dB^2$$
where $ds_0^2$ is non-zero only for vectors tangent to $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and $dB^2$ is non-zero only for vectors tangent to $B$. Then $O(1,3) \times O(D)$ is the group that preserves this form, but the full structure group is larger, since we can for example mix coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and on $B$.

The compactness, or rather the topology of $B$, can enter only in that there is a topological obstruction to consistently defining spinors on a manifold. This condition is global and so if the space $B$ is not nice enough, $R^{1,3} \times B$ may not even have spinors. The technical formulation of the condition is that the second Stiefel-Whitney class should vanish.

Comment: Hi. This is a very insteresting answer. Could you perhaps expand a little on the last point, namely the global condition on the topology of $B$. I am not fimiliar with this Stiefel-Whitney Classes. Thank you.

Comment: I am not very familiar with them myself unfortunately. You can look in *Spin Geometry* by Harvey and Michelson but I found that book very difficult

Comment: @RobinEkman thanks, your answer is being very useful. Nonetheless, I don't know what you mean by structure group. Also, in the review I am reading it says that a "spinor of SO(1,3+D) can be decomposed into a product of spinors of SO(1,3) and of SO(D)". Any idea how to justify this?

Comment: @RobinEkman I mean is there a reason to expect that the spinors in this space-time be always a product of a SO(1,3) spinor with a SO(D) spinor?

Comment: I don't think you can expect that every spinor is a product in that way, but maybe every spinor is a linear combination of products, which is good enough when everything is (multi)linear. Oh, and the book *Spin Geometry* is by Lawson and Michelson, not Harvey and Michelson. I misremembered.

Comment: I made an edit to define the structure group.

Comment: By Stiefel-Whitney class, do you refer to the Stiefel Whitney class of the tangent bundle, or some other bundle?

Comment: The tangent bundle.

Comment: @RobinEkman ok, that's helpful thanks! by the way I think that in the review I am reading what you call structure group is called the "tangent space group", is  this term familiar to you?

Comment: No, but it sounds like it could mean the same thing.